# Automatically add category to post when published

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to add one category **automatically** to a post when I hit "published" , perhaps by creating a function to put in functions.php ? This will save me time instead of scrolling through a ton of categories to tick off. For example, assign the category "awesome" to all posts (while retaining the categories that each post already has been assigned).

**Brainstorm Method A**

Is it possible accomplish this by making a function out of `wp_set_post_categories` or `wp_set_object_terms` for the category called "awesome" ? I do not understand the codex enough to customize it to fit my needs.

```
<?php wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories, $append ) ?> 
or 
<?php wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append ); ?>
```

**Brainstorm Method B**

Also, I stumbled on [this code below](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/automatically-categorize-and-tag-posts-when-saved/) but do not know how to use it. Will the below code work for me? If yes, how would you customize this code for a category called "awesome" ? And are there places in the code that I need to replace with my information ? Or would you suggest using the above codes instead ? Or another method ?

**"CODE A": Automatically categorize and tag posts when saved ( taken from wpsnipp.com )**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'update_post_terms' );
function update_post_terms( $post_id ) {
    if ( $parent = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        $post_id = $parent;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( $post->post_type != 'post' )
        return;
    // add a tag
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'new tag', 'post_tag', true );
    // add a category
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
    $newcat    = get_term_by( 'name', 'Some Category', 'category' );
    array_push( $categories, $newcat->term_id );
    wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $categories );
}
?>
```

Comment: see the "How to add a default category" instructions here: http://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/create-a-post-form-and-display-the-results/#kb-how-to-set-a-default-category

Comment: But the default category in WordPress is only selected when **no other categories are selected** , right? How can I ensure that a category will **always** be selected despite already having assigned other categories to a post ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just go the easy route and do it with jQuery. Put the ID of the desired category in the selector (`#in-category-7` in this example):

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'mark_default_category' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php',     'mark_default_category' );

function mark_default_category() 
{
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $('#in-category-7').prop('checked',true);
        });             
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

To do it with hooks and all that, research for [`save_post` + `wp_insert_term`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bsave_post%20%2Bwp_insert_term%20is%3Aanswer). In those search results I haven't found an example of refined `save_post` (and it **needs** to be). Search only for `save_post` for good examples.